# PCRE regexp contains '.' matche all string instead of a part

Tags: regex, pcre

here is my regexp:

```
/bar.*\d\sfoo/
```

input string:

```
bar something 1 foo bar something 2 foo bar
```

it's matches:

```
bar something 1 foo bar something 2 foo
```

instead of:

```
bar something 1 foo
bar something 2 foo
```

Is there way to solve this ?
Note: something is any characters, except new line.

Comment: You haven't accepted any answers yet. Please accept those helped you.

Answer (score 3):

You should make the `*` reluctant, or lazy, by adding a `?` after it:

```
/bar.*?\d\sfoo/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "lazy" operator "?" to match minimum of the pattern,else
it matches till maximum match.
Here is corrected version :

```
/bar.*?\d\sfoo/
```

See here : 
http://regexr.com?309sa